# How do mathematicians know when writing papers if their results have already been proven or are special cases?

Tags: soft-question, publishing, mathematicians

How does a mathematician know if what they are trying to show or what they are working on has already been shown by someone else, or has already been extensively studied etc.?

What if instead someone has already proven a much stronger result, for which their result is just a special case so though while no one has explicitly written about their special case it follows from the stronger generalization already known?

Also how would they know if maybe their result is actually just trivial to people highly specialized in the field of study they are working in, so though while no one has explicitly ever published anything on it, that was simply because those really deep in that area could prove it trivially?

My thinking is basically those interested in whatever area they are working keep track of journals that publish stuff in that field. But how would you know which journals do that? Are there just like a crap load and you have to keep tabs on them all? Is there something more centralized people look through? But even disregarding this, for the sake of argument if we assume they have "access" to all the work in their field, how would they know how to sort through it to make sure what they are working on hasn't already been well studied etc. with their result already known? What if after searching with every keyword they could think of they still find nothing? What would they do then?

If for example you said the hell with it and just put it out there through a journal or something, and it later turns out it has indeed already been proven, would that reflect badly on you? Can/do you "retract" the paper (not sure if thats a thing) once you know about it?

If theoretically something published could reflect bad on you, could/do people publish under fake names and then if it gets attention re-attach their real name? Or is that like ethically bad? I mean can you even do that? I imagine some fancy journal or whatever would want confirmation of your real identity or something, right?

Do people get taught how to do this specifically in grad school or whenever they start trying to do research? I imagine its changed quite a bit with the widespread use of the web in the past $25$ years. Can any professional mathematican answer if they were taught specifically by someone at a university on how to do this, when they first started doing research?

Did they have like an advisor sit them down and be like "Okay so you try to do this and you look here and then you want to make sure blah blah" or was this something you picked up on your own?

I imagine any practicing mathematician would have had to adapt with the increasing use of the internet, so even if they were taught how to search for stuff through books say in the $1990$s they had to learn on their own how to do it with the web after graduating and being on their own so to speak. Can any older mathematician here tell me how they learned to do this by themselves?

Comment: (probably by asking them)

Comment: @user202729 asking who? What if you had no idea that there was already some general theory around whatever it is you were studying, and that such "experts" even existed? Perhaps your exact thing or whatever already has a name, but you don't know it, so you try your best to describe it in terms of other things but still come up empty. How would you search for that?

Comment: $(1)\;$Web search;$\;(2)\;$Literature search;$\;(3)\;$Ask others in the field, either directly, or by email.

Comment: @quasi Google for a web search? Also what do you mean by literature search?

Comment: Usually, when you try to publish your result, there will be an observant and knowledgeable reviewer to point it out to you. Or not, and then you'll have a "duplicate". Which happens all the time. And is probably ever more frequent as it becomes more and more difficult to keep an overview of the field.

Comment: Professional mathematicians are usually highly specialised, they research in an area covered by a few dozen persons on the whole planet, and they follow the literature. So yes, they know, in most cases. Accidents may happen: one of my results was obtained earlier (though not exactly in the same form) by a physicist, once. That didn't stop us to become good friends, though.

Comment: @user3865391 There are better search tools than google for this (although the ones I've seen are behind paywalls).

Comment: @Raskolnikov So was my theory about the keeping track a bunch of journals or whatever wrong? Is there some kind of "centralized" database or whatever where people can search, specifically for papers on whatever area they are looking into?

Comment: @user3865391: Why not both?${}{}{}$.

Comment: @Arthur Which search tools are you referring to?

Comment: @littleO I used MathSciNet a lot back when I did my masters, but [this wikipedia list has more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_academic_databases_and_search_engines), if you're willing to wade through everything else on that list.

Comment: @user3865391: Literature search means checking journals for titles or abstracts that might match your topic. An important resource, if you can get access to it, is "Mathematical Reviews".$\;$http://www.ams.org/mr-database

Comment: @quasi So that would be a lot better then something like google scholar right? (sorry if that sounds retarded, it might be a simple obvious yes, though i dont know anything about this and am curious)

Comment: @user3865391: A serious literature search is potentially a long process. You should try to use all resources, to make sure you're not missing something.

Comment: @quasi When I was working as a mathematician,"Mathematical Reviews" was the main tool to follow mathematical publications (and some of the reviews were written by me). Nowadays, the situation may be more complicated, because some mathematicians try to fight some publishers claiming to own science.

Comment: @quasi So quasi, I basically went to "https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html" and am trying to navigate through all the widgets, it seems like a lot. Do people get like taught how to do this specifically in grad school or whenever they start trying to do research? I imagine its changed quite a bit with the widespread use of the web in the past 25 years. Were you taught by someone at a university or something how to do this?

Comment: @user3865391: It's a learning curve. Take it slow. Find online help, ask other researchers, don't expect immediate results. Once you find some articles that relate to your topic, the references cited by that article can lead you further. I think the comments so far give you enough guidance to get started. Good luck!

Comment: @quasi Thank you for your help, I'm actually not very well educated and don't have anything to publish but I was just curious.

Comment: @Arthur Do Academics still find the dusty bound journals stacked in University Libraries or are most Mathematics journals digital now? When I completed my PhD, I could've setup my student room in the library, for the amount of time I was spending in the journals section vastly outweighed the time I spent at home.

Comment: I have not experience, but my idea is that every professional mathematician has/had an professional environment, senior mathematicians ( with independence of their age, experienced mathematicians with this knowledge) from who the mathematician learn how work, perhaps by adaptive experience. I think that such senior mathematician have a historical memory about what results have been worked on, and an experience gained about what things may or may not be potentially interesting (also they could have sources of information about what ideas can be relevant). Good week.

Comment: @Kevin I have not had to use pysical copies of any journals more than a few times so far. Almost everything is available in digital form.

Comment: About keeping track of journals: I think most people now just keep track of new additions to arXiv within their main area (so for example, I have an RSS feed of everything new added to [gr.group-theory] and [rt.representation-theory], and this keeps me up to date with what new results get shown).